# Transparent background on winforms with PictureBox opacity

Tags: c#, winforms, background, transparent

I am trying to achieve a full screen Windows Form with a Transparent background, and with images floating  in the form. And for each images have a specific alpha/opacity.

I have tried several solutions that I found on other posts, but none of them is working. Here is the code that I use to test differents setups.

This code create a full screen form with a transparent background and 2 image

- 1 rectangle in (200,0) with a width of 200 and a height of 200, red with an alpha/opacity of 200 (255 is the max alpha/opacity)
- 1 rectangle in (0,200) with a width of 200 and a height of 200, red with an alpha/opacity of 100

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ScreenViewer
{
    public partial class FormDisplay : Form
    {
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (true)
                base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        }
        public FormDisplay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var data1 = new { top = 0, left = 200, width = 200, height = 200, alpha = 200 };
            var data2 = new { top = 200, left = 0, width = 200, height = 200, alpha = 100 };

            if(true)
                if (false)
                {
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
                    BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    TransparencyKey = BackColor;
                } else {
                    TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
                    BackColor = Color.Magenta;
                }

            PictureBox pbx_1 = new PictureBox{AutoSize = true,Dock = DockStyle.None,Visible = true, Location = new Point(data1.left, data1.top) };
            Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(data1.width, data1.height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1)) { g.Clear(Color.Red); }
            bmp1 = SetAlpha(bmp1, data1.alpha);
            pbx_1.Image = bmp1;

            PictureBox pbx_2 = new PictureBox { AutoSize = true, Dock = DockStyle.None, Visible = true, Location = new Point(data2.left, data2.top) };
            Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(data2.width, data2.height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2)) { g.Clear(Color.Red); }
            bmp2 = SetAlpha(bmp2, data2.alpha);
            pbx_2.Image = bmp2;

            bmp1.Save("test1.Png", ImageFormat.Png);
            bmp2.Save("test2.Png", ImageFormat.Png);
            Controls.Add(pbx_1);
            Controls.Add(pbx_2);
        }

        static Bitmap SetAlpha(Bitmap bmpIn, int alpha)
        {
            Bitmap bmpOut = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height);
            float a = alpha / 255f;
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height);
            float[][] matrixItems = {
                new float[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, a, 0},
                new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
            ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(matrixItems);
            ImageAttributes imageAtt = new ImageAttributes();
            imageAtt.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut))
                g.DrawImage(bmpIn, r, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAtt);
            return bmpOut;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this result where the image show the Color.Magenta of the form for the image that has the alpha set to 100, instead of being transparent. The image can be checked as there as saved under test1.png and test2.png:

[image]

Comment: If you don't draw the bitmaps on your PictureBox controls, what happens?

Comment: @Neil If I do not draw one of the image (I comment the line `pbx_1.Image = bmp1;`), then I do not see anything (I do not see the Color.Magenta, as if I set `bmp1 = SetAlpha(bmp1, 0)`; the result is the same).

Comment: I think the problem is that you are not interacting with a 'bitmap'.  Each control is created separately 'off-screen', and then composited on-screen individually.  If you capture the whole screen (or at least the total square of what you want to overwrite), to a bitmap, then draw onto that, and then copy that back on screen, I think you will see what you want to see.

Comment: @Neil Sorry, I am not sure to understand what you mean.

Comment: @Neil That can work, but you'll have a lot of flickering if the Form can be moved. If the Form cannot be moved, it works perfectly fine. -- To move a transparent Window with semi-transparent elements on it, you need something different. You could try with a *sandwich* of 2 Forms. No guarantees of success. At least if you expect *great results* in all situations. -- DoubleBuffering and Transparency are not exactly friends.

Comment: @Neil ok, the idea was to take a screenshot and to add my element on the screenshot; and display the composed image? That would cause issue for the framerate and performances.